# How does one mark something in a pdf and jumps to the part in the code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

i think this is something that might be well-known but i could not find it online. So since this depends on the editor i am using visual code right now. I would like to know if there is a way to jump to the part in the code when you mark something in the pdf. This would be really useful since i need a lot of time to just search for the bits i want to rewrite or change. Thanks in advance:) It does not let me post it this way even whough i think its a valid question so lets be more concrete with an example.

[image]

I want to be able to mark something in this manner and jump to the part in the code where this bit is written.

Comment: you need a pdf reader (e.g. sumatra, but also many of the built-in pdf reader of tex editors) and an editor which supports synctex.

Comment: Ahhh synctex was the solution. Thank you very much!